# use php function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var oMain = new CMain({
      win_occurrence: 40, //WIN PERCENTAGE.SET A VALUE FROM 0 TO 100.
      slot_cash: 200, //THIS IS THE CURRENT SLOT CASH AMOUNT. THE GAME CHECKS IF THERE IS AVAILABLE CASH FOR WINNINGS.
      bonus_occurrence: 15, //SET BONUS OCCURRENCE PERCENTAGE IF PLAYER GET A WIN. SET A VALUE FROM 0 TO 100. (IF 100%, PLAYER GET A BONUS EVERYTIME THERE IS A WIN).
      min_reel_loop: 1, //NUMBER OF REEL LOOPS BEFORE SLOT STOPS  
      reel_delay: 0, //NUMBER OF FRAMES TO DELAY THE REELS THAT START AFTER THE FIRST ONE
      time_show_win: 2000, //DURATION IN MILLISECONDS OF THE WINNING COMBO SHOWING
      time_show_all_wins: 2000, //DURATION IN MILLISECONDS OF ALL WINNING COMBO
      money: <?php $kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye ?>, //STARING CREDIT FOR THE USER
      min_bet: 0.05, //MINIMUM COIN FOR BET
      max_bet: 0.5, //MAXIMUM COIN FOR BET
      max_hold: 3, //MAXIMUM NUMBER OF POSSIBLE HOLD ON REELS
      perc_win_prize_1: 50, //OCCURENCE PERCENTAGE FOR PRIZE 1 IN BONUS
      perc_win_prize_2: 35, //OCCURENCE PERCENTAGE FOR PRIZE 2 IN BONUS
      perc_win_prize_3: 15, //OCCURENCE PERCENTAGE FOR PRIZE 3 IN BONUS
      num_symbol_bonus: 3, //NUMBER OF BONUS SYMBOLS (DEFAULT IS SYMBOL 9) THAT MUST BE SHOWN TO ACHIEVE THE BONUS PANEL
      num_spin_ads_showing: 10 //NUMBER OF SPIN TO COMPLETE, BEFORE TRIGGERING AD SHOWING.
      //// THIS FUNCTIONALITY IS ACTIVATED ONLY WITH CTL ARCADE PLUGIN.///////////////////////////
      /////////////////// YOU CAN GET IT AT: /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // http://codecanyon.net/item/ctl-arcade-wordpress-plugin/13856421 ///////////
    });
</script>
```

Hello, here is the code I wanna use PHP function in this JavaScript.

```
money: <?php $kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye ?>
```

I wrote it like this but that is not working for me.

Comment: <?php $kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye ?> like that working for me but thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print any text in PHP you should use the `echo` or `print` function. So this line:

```
<?php $kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php echo $kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye; ?>
```

Edit: As far as I know is that you can't pass a PHP string without using the quotes in your javascript code otherwise you will get errors like

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

So replace:

```
money: <?php $kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye ?>
```

With this:

```
money: '<?php echo $kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye; ?>',
```

Comment: i used echo then i got that error in console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @ХусейнБаккал ok, my bad. It's because you didn't show all of the codes, but that's ok! Check the output from `$kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye`. Also you need to pass a string to the `money` key. So it should be like: `money: '<?php echo $kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye; ?>'`

Comment: @ХусейнБаккал for this answer to work, you probably would have to put the `<?php echo ... ?>` between quote marks.: `mode: "<?php echo ... ?>"`

Comment: i used quote marks there is no error but code is not working

Comment: That brings us to step to of debugging. Check the output of your PHP script, does it return anything you asked for?

Comment: yup i just saw now there is another errors because i changed something in javascript. https://pastebin.com/xF13xuiT here. now will share all that js files

Comment: https://pastebin.com/A0ma9iip (CGame.js)
https://pastebin.com/A6863mBn (Cmenu.js)
https://pastebin.com/rG36dqPw (CInterface.js)

Comment: anyone can help me? how can i add php function in js file?

Answer (score 0):

As @Variable pointed out. if you would like to output a string, you will need to add quotes around it.

An alternative to have a proper typecast in JS is using `json_encode`, example:

```
{
    ...
    money: <?php echo json_encode($kullanici_bilgileri->bakiye) ?>,
    ...
}
```

With this approach, you don't need to worry about forgetting the quotes.